# How to use parse_json within a string?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column (TAG) that is STRING value (not a JSON) that looks like this:

```
TAG:
{"country":{"name":"spring","description":"2021"}}
```

I am trying to only select what is right after "name", so "spring". Is there a way to do this? I've tried parse_json, but it is not working.

```
select upper(parse_json(TAG):country:name::string) as name
from TBL_a
```

Comment: I am not able to reproduce an issue with what you have.  Can you provide an error message?  Your Snowflake syntax works for me without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select upper(TRY_PARSE_JSON(
    jsondata: TAG.country
  ): name) AS name from tbl_A
```

Or you could even use standard sql for this usecase

```
 Select upper(
   Substr(tag, INSTR("name", tag) +2, INSTR(",", 
    tag) - 1)) from table
```

Comment: I don't think either of these work in Snowflake, which it seems is the OP request.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work just fine to me:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT '{"country":{"name":"spring","description":"2021"}}' as str
    )
SELECT upper(parse_json(str):country:name::string)
FROM x;
```